# Join raspbian in a samba domain

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, samba, domain, raspbian

I'm trying for an `rpi` in a `samba` domain. I researched a lot but nothing works ...

I would ask for a tutorial from you guys or even the link to some that worked. I'll use the same `raspbian`.

I'm really in doubt about what might be failing, I will not even put `smb.conf` or anything like that, because I've tried different things ... I want to go from scratch myself, to understand and see how it's done.

Thank you immensely who can help! (~°-°)~

EDIT 1:
The tutorials I found were similar to this [site](https://raspberrytips.com/join-active-directory-raspberry-pi/) but with some distinctions in some parts.
Does anyone have or give me a tutorial on what worked? Thank you! :D

Comment: It should be no different than any other Debian, Ubuntu, etc. What have you researched on your own and tried already?

Comment: The tutorials I found were similar to this: [link](https://raspberrytips.com/join-active-directory-raspberry-pi/)

But they did not work ... I suppose it could be `smb.conf` but now it has become a mess. Hahahaha (laughing with sadness).

Anything I see about formatting the SD card but I need to know if this is really right.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching on internet And i found the following information:

https://www.kerstnet.at/2018/11/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-with-samba-4-on-a-raspberry-pi

To add raspbian into a samba Domain seems to be needed some additional samba configuration pretty similar to a server Domain client.

Comment: The link did not work ... But I found it, would that be it?
https://www.kerstner.at/2018/11/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-with-samba-4-on-a-raspberry-pi-3/